# How can I make Shutter open at startup?

Tags: boot, startup

How can i make the application, Shutter (takes screenshots) open at startup? I know about sys > prefs > statup applications, but after I go to add what do I fill out the form with? Shutter isn't a command, is it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### For Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04

---

You can drag and drop the Shutter menu item <sup>(Applications ➜ Accessories ➜ Shutter)</sup> into
the *Startup Applications* window and it will be added to the list of applications that start on login.

[image]

Comment: You can drag and drop! Wow thanks for teaching me something today :)

Answer (score 13):

For the command, add `shutter --min_at_startup` to make it startup minimized.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you answered the question yourself. Go to `System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications` and add a new item with "Shutter" (or something else) as the name and `shutter` as the command.

Comment: Make sure you put `shutter` exactly as mniess typed it--all lower-case.

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 11.10 and Above

---

Refer to this Question, [How do I add/remove the "hidden" startup applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-do-i-add-remove-the-hidden-startup-applications) and specally to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/152413/24621) to know how to access the startup applications

Then click on `ADD` and type this command in the `CUSTOM` field:

> sh -c "sleep 50 && shutter --min_at_startup &"

You can change the time of the sleep if you want it to be launched earlier.

Comment: @ Suhaib (or anybody), why add the `sleep`?

Comment: @PaulvanLeeuwen I  have an old laptop.  command that I wrote launches at login = slow startup. So wait until you finish logging-in then start it

Comment: Even on a slow machine I would not expect this to be necessary... Interesting. What result did you get when you tried it without the sleep? Did shutter not start at all? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating bash script, because non of other solutions working for me.

```
cd ~/.local/bin
```

Create file `shut-ter-auto-launch` with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

process=shutter
makerun="shutter --min_at_startup"

while true
do
  if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $process
  then
    break
  else
    nohup $makerun &
  fi
  sleep 5
done

exit
```

Allow to execute it:

```
chmod +x shut-ter-auto-launch
```

Untick "Launch at login" option at Shutter preferences.

Add `shut-ter-auto-launch` to `Startup Applications`.

Shutter will launch after any other GUI app is launched.