# How to make sudo remember my password and how to add an application to startup

Tags: 10.04, startup, sudo

I guess this should be a simple thing for ubuntu users out there. I have two questions.

1. Whenever I need to run some command that requires permission from root, I run as sudo followed by that command. It would be nice if that does not prompt for password (but I should still be issuing a sudo to make sure that I know what I am doing). How to do this?
2. Every time I start my system, I go to terminal and start my VPN using sudo vpnc. This is almost everytime! How to automate this to a startup script?

Help much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Part 2 of your question is similar to: [How can I make Shutter open at startup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8911/how-can-i-make-shutter-open-at-startup)

Comment: Please do not ask two different questions in one question. Make them separate questions so they can be objectively answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### First Question

- If you dont want to enter password everytime,then you should edit sudoers file.

  `sudo visudo`
- Then add the following line at the end of the file.

  `%username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

  [image]
- Now if you enter sudo followed by the command  it wont prompt you to enter password.

---

### Second Question

- For your second question you can add that command `sudo vpnc` to startup applications.
- To add that command in startup applications Goto System **→** Preferences **→** Startup Applications.

  [image]

Comment: where did you get the lime green theme? It will go wonderfully with my desktop background :)

Comment: @rumtscho It's tropical theme :) Installation instruction is [here ](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/9-great-gnome-themes-with-ubuntu.html).

Comment: Your computer's your own, but I would suggest being a little careful about blanket NOPASSWD. You could do it for specific commands, so that you can run `vpnc` without a password, but not `rm -rf /`.

Answer (score 1):

Tag the users or groups who you want to have passwordless access to sudo with "NOPASSWD" in your sudoers file (`sudo visudo` to edit it). See the man page for sudoers for more details.

You can then create a startup script by editing the appropriate file for the shell you're using -- .profile, or .bashrc, or .cshrc, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In 10.04 I see that in the Network Manager (v0.8) I have a flag on the VPN Configuration screen (System > Preference > Network Connections , click the VPN tab, select the connection and "Edit") "Connect Automatically" I believe that it fires up the selected connection at login.

Comment: It might be required to install network-manager-vpnc & network-manager-vpnc-gnome [ ![Install VPNC plugin for Network Manager](http://bit.ly/software-small) ](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/network-manager-vpnc-gnome) for that to work. (Or the equivalent KDE-package when using Kubuntu.)

Comment: Sorry, for the broken link, but there seems to be a bug in the Markdown parser...   :-(  Try clicking [this link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/network-manager-vpnc-gnome) instead.