# start lampp at startup as root

Tags: startup, sudo, root, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make sudo remember my password and how to add an application to startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21343/how-to-make-sudo-remember-my-password-and-how-to-add-an-application-to-startup)

I have lampp installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 Everything works very fine and now I would like to start the lampp-server on startup.

I have a startlampp.sh script with this:

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./lampp start
```

code in it. It is enabled for execution and when I run it in terminal I am asked for the password and finally it starts lampp.

Can I include the password in the script that it runs on startup?

Greetings philipp

Comment: Your question is very much similar to [How to make sudo remember my password and how to add an application to startup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21343/how-to-make-sudo-remember-my-password-and-how-to-add-an-application-to-startup?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the **rc.local** file to auto start lampp.

use root login and edit `/etc/rc.local` file and add line `/opt/lampp/lampp start` to end of the file.

Reboot the machine and you can check the status of the lampp using `/opt/lampp/lampp status`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: /etc/rc does not exist. Should I make it?

Comment: check `etc/rc.local` if you don't find it then please refer this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup)

Comment: It works for me. Just put  /opt/lampp/lampp start before exit 0 of rc.local file