# How do I add/remove the "hidden" startup applications?

Tags: startup

How do I manage (add/remove) all the startup applications in Ubuntu 11.10 and up?

*Startup Applications* doesn't show all the applications which are started during boot.

Comment: Your link not work. I have tried all answer but .. not work

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @tijybba yes. I am using 12.04. However, after restarting, I can see list of programs. Thanks . This question is dublicate. Please give vote to close .

Comment: Okey-Dokey , so please Up-vote my comment :D :)

Answer (score 50):

As said above, you have to edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and either:

- remove the `NoDisplay=true` lines;
- or make those same lines comments by adding `#` in front of them;
- or replace `true` by `false` in those same lines.

The third solution can be easily done in three steps:

1. Summon the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type the two following commands:

   ```
   cd /etc/xdg/autostart/
   sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
   ```

After changing anything you want, you can go back to the previous state by typing this into the terminal:

```
sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=false/NoDisplay=true/g' *.desktop
```

This has been tested in 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04.

[Source: [iloveubuntu.net](http://iloveubuntu.net/how-enable-all-apps-startup-applications-ubuntu-1110), thank you Nikhil Sinha for the link]

Comment: how can you disable them if you do not have root access? these start gnome apps for KDE which I don't want

Comment: Can also be found here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShowHiddenStartupApplications

Comment: The first suggestion has worked for me. I just `cd /etc/exdg/autostart` and removed the program I wanted to remove from the autostart directory. You can view autostart programs by run `ls` and from the list you can see the application or program you want to remove.

Comment: if you edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/` be aware, that you should undo those changes before you upgrade your system, otherwise you will get a question if you want to keep the edited .desktop files or use the package maintainers default for **each** of those files! A better solution is to create files in `~/.config/autostart/` as suggested in  @TormodVolden 's answer

Answer (score 16):

Remove the `NoDisplay=true` line from each entry in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` Then just uncheck the ones you don't want in Startup Applications. Generally though the autostart apps are there for a reason so make sure you know what you're doing when you disable them.

There are also various services which store their configuration files in `/etc/init`. Most users shouldn't touch those files though.

Comment: Jeremy - Thanks for the tip. BTW, used BUM (bootup-manager) to disable many of the services which I don't use and shaved the boot time. I liked Ubuntu, but 11.10 ignored some basic things, like adding users to groups from UI, screen savers, easily modifying unity launcher icons. I am not a big fan of UI, but a UI will easily get more people on-board.

Answer (score 13):

The correct way to do this as a normal user is to copy the desktop file in question from `/etc/xdg/autostart/` to `~/.config/autostart/` (create the directory first if needed) and edit this copy to state `NoDisplay=false`. Then open "Startup Applications Preferences" and uncheck the corresponding box.

Now you need to remove the `NoDisplay=true` key from the files after copying them, which can be done with `sed` for all of them with

```
sed -i '/NoDisplay=true/s/^/#/' ~/.config/autostart/*.desktop
```

Comment: You still need to remove the `NoDisplay=true` key from the files after copying them, which can be done with `sed -i '/NoDisplay=true/s/^/#/' ~/.config/autostart/*.desktop`.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do this, because it will ensure that changes are persisted even when the application updates.

Comment: remember to check the files in `~/.config/autostart/` after a system upgrade for any changes compared to the default files in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` in case something was added during upgrade

Answer (score 9):

It's normal that you don't see anything listed. The *Additional startup programs* list is just for programs that start up for the current user (not necessarily for other users, and not all the services that start when Ubuntu boots). Furthermore, it doesn't list the normal parts of the desktop environment that start when the user logs in graphically.

[image: You can check here]

Anyone can check this by clicking "Startup applications". Its blank by default.

[image]

If you want to have the hidden startup entries shown (such as update notifier, orca screen reader, onboard, etc), just type/copy and paste the following in a terminal:

```sh
find /etc/xdg/autostart ~/.config/autostart -name \*.desktop -exec sudo sed –i -e '/^NoDisplay=/d' {} +
```

If you want to hide the normally hidden entries, just type/copy and paste the following

```sh
echo NoDisplay=true | find /etc/xdg/autostart ~/.config/autostart -name \*.desktop -exec sudo tee -a {} + >/dev/null
```

Source: [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/192104/how-to-showhide-all-hidden-startup-applications-in-ubuntu-14.10/)

Comment: when I click to program, it shows nothing .

Comment: Yeah its blank by default.

Comment: I recommend you delete this answer, @BigGenius -- the OP knows its blank which is why he's asking us :)

Comment: If you read above comment. They are also doubt if its blank or populated by default.

Comment: I think BigGenius is right. There are no StartUp programs enabled by default so the list is blank.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative:

To view all startup applications at "**startup applications**" just open `/etc/xdg/autostart` and modifying the line `NoDisplay=true` to `#NoDisplay=true`. Just add an `#` . 
Then you will be able to see all at "**startup applications**" and disable what you want from there.