# Startup Applications missing from System Settings screen. Where can I find it?

Tags: 11.10, startup-applications

I have read related questions here, but my problem in 11.10 is:

I have no "startup apps" item in "system setting" at all. How can I get it back?

[image: System Settings]

Comment: This is  *not* a duplicate of [How to manage the startup applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-to-manage-the-startup-applications).

Comment: Run `gnome-session-properties` to start it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Startup Applications can be found in the Panel in the upper right of the screen below the screen icon:

[image]

HTH. Have a nice day. :)

Just moved a bit, but it is there.

Comment: Thats what I  ask about - read my Q again: I have no "startup applications" item in the "system settings" window.

Comment: Thank you very much - I see it now :-)     Just I'm wondering, why is this item not in "system config" (too), as expected.

Comment: @kapetr - you are welcome, looks like I have to thank Takkat for the assist here with the screen capture. ;)

Comment: grr... I wish it showed up when typing "Startup Applications" in the dash...

Answer (score 0):

Read it here ....

http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-get-classic-start-menu-with-unity-launcher-ubuntu/

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you - I have to say, I'm not happy at all with new Ubuntu interface (Unity). But I'm afraid we all will have to live with it in future. So I will try to use this nice but  very impractical "thing".

Comment: @kapetr: the more you use it the more you will like it. I missed it so much that I had to upgrade my 10.04 productive machine recently.

Comment: To search app is more or less a horror. It takes > 15 seconds before the app search is available (the "app" icon appears in Alt+F2 or in dash). I want app menu back - it have take less then 1 second to find my app in the tree. Now ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the system tray issue and came across the parting laments regarding Unity.

All you have to do is open your terminal and type `sudo apt-get install gnome`-or-search gnome-fallback for gnome shell options.  The only thing I missed was Users and Groups, it seems Gnome tools were not included, but another search found that as a solved issue (so the package is available).

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the question in this case.  Further dialogue not relating to the original question should be done in comments.