# "no system tray detected on this system."

Tags: system-tray

"no system tray detected on this system." Appears starting Gnome and Cinnamon in Oneiric 11.10; starting with Gnome Classic and Unity no problem at all. How to solve?

Comment: Did you install hplip?

Comment: @Rinzwind: That question deserves some explanation. To my eyes, it seems like it could possibly be meant for another question. :)

Comment: Yes, I installed hplip; the problem is not the printer. Some explanation: The full pop-up starting Oneiric-desktop-choice Gnome", or "Cinnamon" is: "No system tray detected on this system. Unable to start, exiting ."

Comment: @ Jo-Erlend Schinstad not if you knew what the problem is ;)

Comment: This issue seems to have returned on Ubuntu 20.04 after recent updates (Nov/Dec 2020).

Answer (score 15):

I had this error on every boot on ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver after installing the drivers for my HP printer.

I just deleted the file

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop
```

to get rid of the problem.

Comment: If you don't want to remove it, changing its extension also works, for example extension **old**: `/etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop.old`

Answer (score 14):

In your start up programs there is a  line regarding starting `hplip`.
Change ...

```
sh -c "sleep 15; exec hp-systray"
```

to

```
sh -c "sleep 45; exec hp-systray"
```

and the problem is gone.

`hplip` is expecting a system tray and that got removed (and was changed into notification area). All this does is postpone startup of `hp-systray` so if your system is slow to respond this notice might come back and bite you again.

Found it here on [Bugzilla](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/335662) (has a `fix released` on 2011.11.25 (...)). 
Besides the bug I found the following sources: [Linuxquestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/hplip-no-system-tray-detected-910957/), [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1136879)

Comment: Thank ouy Rinzwind for your answer. BUT: where can I find that line in my Start-up programs "sh -c" etc.? I tried Grub, .hplip and the systray-itself,start-up programs.

Comment: Not a problem @tonwillems.pc :) if the answer is what you needed do not forget to accept it ;)

Comment: BUT: where can I find that line in my Start-up programs "sh -c" etc.? I tried Grub, .hplip and the systray-itself,start-up programs.

Comment: see freecode's comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74031/startup-applications-missing-from-system-settings-screen-where-can-i-find-it

Comment: Thanks a lot for last link given. Yesterday in my update was a patch for the "no system tray"-issue: I quote:PROPOSED UPDATE.....

Comment: Excellent! @tonwillems.pc glad you got it sorted *O*

Comment: @tonwillems.pc In my hplip there's only "hp-systray -x"

Comment: Which file in the startup are we supposed to change? Please provide a path. Got this error when trying to install hplip-3.18.9.run

Comment: @lovedrinking In Debian 8 (Jessie), you can find the command of interest in the `/etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop` file, where I changed the line of interest from `Exec=hp-systray -x` to `Exec=/bin/sleep 15 && hp-systray -x`. End of problem, for me...dunno if this helps for Ubuntu...

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to start up applications using Launcher
2. Uncheck HP system tray service

[image]

Comment: To bad we can't make it work, though. I was able to restart it and I see the icon, but the icon is not reacting to my clicks...

Comment: For me this is the best solution. Even with a 90 second delay in `/etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop` the problem was not solved for Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Not too sure what happens, but I can now access the menu, only it takes some time to wake up. I do not know how much time. But just after I restarted, the icon doesn't respond for a while.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui
```

will install a newer release of `hplip` that **might** fix the issue.

See

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/335662
- https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/207699

for more discussion of the issue

Comment: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing what does it have to do with printers?

Answer (score 3):

note: you can navigate to `/etc/xdg/autostart`

then look for the file: `hplip-systray.desktop`

In the meantime open a terminal and login as root.

write in terminal:

```
sudo rm  hplip-systray.desktop
```

then drag `hplip-systray.desktop` file and drop it in terminal and hit enter. That's all.

note: or simply login as root in terminal and write:

```
sudo rm  /etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop
```

and hit enter

Comment: I navigated to /etc/xdg/autostart/ and then ran sudo rm -R hplip-systray.desktop which was by far simpler. No error then appeared on reboot.

Comment: I navigated to /etc/xdg/autostart/ and then ran sudo rm -R hplip-systray.desktop which was by far simpler. No error then appeared on reboot. This also worked on 20.04.1

Answer (score 2):

Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui
```

When prompted, choose Yes to install new version/release. After installation, reboot your PC/laptop, and you will see HP GUI in your upper right next to your wifi connection icon.

This was tested on Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=209791&p=1752733#p1752733

I had been using **MenuLibre** (aka 'Menu Editor') to clean up my xdg applications, as there were a bunch of them in bad state after years of hacking.

*(BTW, the `Menu bar | Menu Editor | Parsing Error Log` command produces a nice list of application desktops that are broken in some way or have other errors.)*

So I had edited `~/.local/shared/applications/cinnamon.desktop` just to simply give it a better comment, i.e. that if run it would restart cinnamon.  (As I can now see, it also starts cinnamon, like initially.)

But **MenuLibre** had revised it further, and without telling me, and this had broken my ability for Cinnamon's panel and menu to start up.  The background was black, and I could only operate on GUI tool, the most recent one, and there were no close buttons on anything.  ..

(But, note I could right click on the screen and get a terminal and also I could use `Ctl-Alt-F1` to open a tty.)

To find the solution to what had broken I had to restore `~/.local/shared/applications`.  Then little at a time with divide and conquer I located the file that caused the issue, that is after a whole bunch of painful reboots to test it.

**tl;dr: SOLUTION:** Restoring this file fixed things:

```
~/.local/shared/applications/cinnamon.desktop
```