# Ubuntu 20.10 missing "system tray"

Tags: system-tray, 20.10

After testing Ubuntu 20.10 on my two backup computers, and prepping my main computer to take 20.10, I finally updated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 on my main computer. I've still had a few glitches.

Right now, it seems like the "system tray" doesn't exist any more. I say that because I have at least two applications, maybe more, that try to update their system tray icons, and can't.

Can I get back a "system tray"?

**Examples:**

In `HPLIP` HP printer software, there's an app `HPLIP Toolbox` (hplip-systray)...

[image]

In `CherryTree` notes...

[image]

Funny enough, `Calibre` works...

[image]

Comment: As for me this may be a reason to say final "good bye" to GNOME Shell and switch to normal DE like MATE.

Comment: @N0rbert Point noted.

Comment: I have this same problem. I found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/101828/no-system-tray-detected-on-this-system. Note it is nearly identical, but several years old AND with a supposed 'solution'. Could it have been overwritten, re-introducing this bug?

Comment: @MalikA.Rumi Thanks for the lead. I've modified the startup file for hp-systray and we'll see what happens on next login. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps someone but for Ubuntu 22.04 to show icon in system tray i have switched to Xorg, and it worked

[Switch to Xorg detailed:](https://helpdesk.psionline.com/hc/en-gb/articles/13470827149332-How-to-perform-the-switch-from-the-Wayland-display-server-to-Xorg-X11-on-Linux-Ubuntu-22-04-LTS) 
"Step 1. Log out from the system. Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE button and press Log Out.

Step 2. On the Login, screen click on your Username. When Username is selected, find the “gear” icon lower right corner. Click on the “gear” icon and select “Ubuntu on Xorg”. Type your password and hit Enter to login.

Step 3. Open Terminal and run echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE  command to confirm that X11 display server is running."

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tray Icons: Reloaded](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2890/tray-icons-reloaded/)  by [MartinPL](https://extensions.gnome.org/accounts/profile/MartinPL):

> Tray Icons Reloaded is a GNOME Shell extension which bring back Tray Icons to top panel, with additional features.

I had the same problem. I thought it were my extensions, I disabled them one by one, it didn't work. So I thought uninstalling them and installing them again would work.

Then I saw this extension, installed it and now my menu is back.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install Indicator Applet Completer (and add it to my top bar) to see all icons again.
This happened after an upgrade from ubuntu20lts with mate to ubuntu 21.10 with mate.

Comment: Tell us where to get it.