# Where can I find the startup applications in 12.10

Tags: preferences

I'm using 12.10 and am looking for where I can configure the startup applications.  I've read that I can find it in `System > Preferences > Startup Applications`, but that seems to be in a previous version of Ubuntu.  I don't have a `System`, the closest thing I can find is `System Settings`, but it has no `Preferences`.

I also do not see it here: [Startup Applications missing from System Settings screen. Where can I find it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74031/startup-applications-missing-from-system-settings-screen-where-can-i-find-it)

I'm trying to set Pidgin to load on startup, I also do not know it's install path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Dash ( by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> key), and search for `Startup Applications`.
An alternative way is to press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and type `gnome-session-properties`.

Comment: What is the Super key?

Comment: @Webnet it's the Windows key.