# Manually Start Ubuntu One Daemon

Tags: ubuntu-one

I would like to be able to manually start and stop the Ubuntu One Daemon. 
However, I need to know:

1. What is the name of the ubuntu one daemon ?
2. Can I use `update-rc.d (ubuntu one daemon) disable` & to manually start it?
   Any help will be greatly appreciated.

## Updated

Remove It From Auto Starting When System Boots . i did it with update-rc.d bluetooth disable

Comment: Thanks for the question.  Mine said the status was good (u1sdtool -s), but it wasn't.  Running u1sdtool -q and then unsdtool -w fixed it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntuone is autostarted from `/etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop` not from `upstart`. `gnome-session-properties` OR `StartUp Appication Preference` on session-indicator doesnot let you enable/disable the autostart application in `/etc/xdg/autostart` as most of them contain `NoDisplay=true`. What you can do is either:

Comment the line `NoDisplay=true` as `#NoDisplay=true` and disable it from the above mentioned guis.

OR do:

`mv /etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop.disabled`

[How do I add/remove the "hidden" startup applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-to-manage-the-startup-applications)

Answer (score 2):

You may start it by executing `ubuntuone-launch`. The daemon is not handled by upstart, so you may control it using `u1sdtool` ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/u1sdtool.1.html))

`u1sdtool -q` will stop the daemon

Comment: Sir i want remove it from auto starting when system boots ...

Comment: @OneZero, i've updated my answer