# Improve System Performance By Stopping Daemons/Services

Tags: 11.10, boot, services, autostart

> I am trying to improve my system performance by removing some daemon/Services.

On my **Desktop PC** i need to stop some daemons/services Which are Installed by **Default** in Ubuntu From auto starting . & manually start when ever i want to .

Can any one **provide list of daemons/services** which are installed by default in Ubuntu
& it will be ok with manual start just like i did with [Ubuntu one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104652/manually-start-ubuntu-one-daemon)

These are few Services/Daemons i have never used it on my Desktop & **Uninstalled** it
printer , scanner ( saned ) , bluetooth .

> I have Noticed at shutdown that  **acpi** Daemon take 2 to 3 seconds [(Advanced Configuration and Power Interface)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) in help its shows that u can actually turn it off . **can i Uninstall it & is it safe ?** if yes how ?
>
> modem-manager takes up to 2 seconds at shutdown & fail every time pc reboot/shutdown

i have managed to reduce at least 3 to 4 sec at reboot/start Ubuntu , i have made some script so when ever i need that service i just click on script & its on . example [vmware script](http://pastebin.com/YC6KrTfC)

Note: dont want to use extra tools like chkconfig , rcconf .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***chkconfig*** You can see what services are running and disable desired services from being started at boot time, and of course manage the state of a service while your OS is running:

```
    # sudo apt-get install chkconfig
    # sudo chkconfig -s <service> <state/runlevels>
```

And of course :)

```
    # man chkconfig
```

regards,
milo

Comment: Sir dont want extra tools , chkconfig , rcconf

Comment: I understand, ***chkconfig*** has a ***very small*** footprint, it has no dependencies and will only use ***70kB*** of additional disk space after installation. It is the configuration daemon management tool of choice for distributions such as Redhat, so it is highly functional, secure & reliable, not to mention it will do exactly what you require :)

Comment: Sir yes you r rite i m also a Red Hat user , Used chkconfig alot .

Comment: used BootUp-Manager this tool is also nice , in Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Are you sure `chkconfig` is useful on Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't understand the question.