# how to see startup applications?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add/remove the “hidden” startup applications in Ubuntu 11.10 or later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-do-i-add-remove-the-hidden-startup-applications-in-ubuntu-11-10-or-later)

There are basically no applications shown in Startup Applications program.  Thus, I have some questions :

- How can I to make them appear again ?
- How can I disable some program ?

Comment: Go for this http://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-to-manage-the-startup-applications. Also a possible duplicate.