# Chrome Slow in 16.10 with multiple windows in different workspaces

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, workspaces, 16.10

To reproduce:

1. open chrome,
2. open a new window (ctrl-n),
3. move that window to a different workspace,
4. use chrome normally (i.e. open and close new tabs, type into omnibar).

Google Chrome will behave extremely slowly.

This is only after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10. However Chrome Version 55.0.2883.75 (64-bit).

Happy to dig deeper and post logs, etc., but don't really know where to start.

EDIT: Just upgraded Chromium to Version 55.0.2883.87, now Chromium also has the same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. You can disable hardware acceleration and it behaves better, but you can forget about watching youtube videos full screen then. I got around it for now using chromium, altough is not a perfect solution, some pages like amazon video do not work with chromium. Hope someone can find something about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome windows very sluggish when active on different workspaces](http://askubuntu.com/questions/849866/chrome-windows-very-sluggish-when-active-on-different-workspaces)

Comment: @jamesadney you can see that was posted later the same day I posted

Comment: Be that as it may, the called duplicate has an answer. Did you try it?

Comment: yes, works per @JonVallet's comment. only a partial solution

Comment: fyi issue on chromium bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=683486&q=workspace%20slow&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Launchpad issue is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1628866.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a similar issue after updating and upgrading. The problem for me was related to CPU clocking speed. You might give this a try.

1. Disable intel_psate. You can do this by modifying `/etc/default/grub` and adding `intel_pstate=disable` parameter to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line. It should look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"`. Then save the file and run  `sudo update-grub`.
2. Install cpufrequtils package: `sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils`.
3. Edit `/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils` file and set the following line to the governor you need (performance in my case): `GOVERNOR=”performance”`
4. reboot

Comment: It should be 'disable'

Comment: OK I edited. Btw this answer is very hardware specific.

Comment: Thanks and yes it is applicable to someone running an Intel processor. This can be seen by running `lscpu`. I will mention that if it comes up again.

Comment: Thanks, however I don't feel like I should have to mess around with hardware settings to make chrome work, especially if Firefox and older versions of chrome work fine. This should be an issue fixable within Chrome alone, should it not?

Comment: Agreed but if you did a complete update and upgrade to the entire system like stated in the OP, then more than just the programs were downloaded and installed. At any length, it wouldn't hurt to do it for testing purposes.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: Did not help me. Ubuntu 16.04 here

Answer (score 1):

Since you have little detail about your setup I will make some assumptions.
1) you are not using the unity desktop, but something like Gnome Classic. I use flashback/fallback with Metacity, No Compiz compositor or editor to get the 'workspaces' in a row along the bottom panel.
2) maybe you only have 4 GiB for RAM?

To overcome some of the same difficulties I first increased my HP ProBook 440 G1 Laptop to 8 GiB of RAM by adding a 4 GiB stick of the exact same RAM. My CPU (i3) already has 4 cores @ 2.4 GHz., so I was good there.
 I find with Modern OS's and App's 4 GiB's of RAM is not an acceptable amount of RAM.
 My desktops boxes have 16 and 32 GiB  of RAM as you can never have enough RAM
I used `System Profiler and Benchmark` available in the `Ubuntu-Gnome` 14.04.5 `Software Center` to find "How my Setup was doing?" When Version 16x first came out I found too many applications were Missing or not Working in the `Software Center` (perhaps this has been fixed by now), so I opted-out and reinstalled "**Ubuntu-Gnome**" 14.04 (not just Ubuntu, but the one with the **Gnome** included). *I have my particular likes!*
 I used `System Monitor` to see what was running that I did not need or want.
I answered a post ([Why is zero swap being used on my setup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174774/why-is-zero-swap-being-used-on-my-setup/895693#895693)), where there is a discussion about Memory use and I had some Ideas to look at. One of the thins I do is covered in [How do I add/remove the "hidden" startup applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-do-i-add-remove-the-hidden-startup-applications).
One thing I learned is that Firefox uses Ram and Cache as one monolithic Block and Google-chrome or Opera Browser setup multiple Blocks. Not sure what is better as many debate this?, **But** *I have found*, both have a greedy approach to keep stuff in Cache and some RAM just in case you might ever use it again... in effect never releasing the former so other operations/app's might use it!!!
In Summery... Control your startup App's 
    Some are not visible so you will want to edit "someDesktopApp.desktop" (note you need to be in a 'root' file mode to see the *.desktop extension) and change them from

> NoDisplay=false/NoDisplay=true

(link above). You do not need yet another App to control startups as once visible you can check them Off with the menu 
`Applications >> System Tools >> Preferences >> Startup Applications`
Don't go crazy and turn too much off at once, as you may kill something you need or an indicator you want!! do some research on what does what.
Get rid of things like "animations" and other "Eye Candy" The only effective way I have found is to learn and understand "dconf Editor" (A pain in the  a*$  and needs much improvement). Try *ctrl+F* to find stuff.
Try my way to clean the Cache. Some say NOT!!!, but it works for me when things get slow and I don't have to reboot

```
sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

I set it up as a menu item with a file and the link to:

```
#/bin/bash
sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

[locate in /usr/local/bin]

---

*Setup a Menu Item*

[~/.local/share/applications/menulibre-clean-ubuntu-cache.desktop]
(I like menulibre better then alacarte)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Clean Ubuntu Cache
Comment=To free pagecache, dentries and inodes:
Icon=aptdaemon-update-cache
Exec=gksudo /usr/local/bin/clean_cache
NoDisplay=false
Categories=menulibre-favorites1
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false

Actions=NewShortcut;

[Desktop Action NewShortcut]
Name=clean 3
Exec=sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
#OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

In the line above... `Categories=menulibre-favorites1` ... is for my personal Menu category so you might want to set it to something different

Hope this helps. Something to think about anyway
James Niland