# Update Manager doesn't show up anymore when there are available updates

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

Like the title says the Update Manager doesn't show up automatically,like it used to do, when there are available updates.To be more specific ,the only way I can update my packages/installed programs is either via Terminal or run open manually the Update Manager.Does anybody know how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Follow this tutorial to display hidden startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-do-i-add-remove-the-hidden-startup-applications). Then head to `Startup Applications`

[image]

and look whether `Update Notifier` is checked:

[image]

Activate the entry, if it isn't.

**Edit**: If the entry doesn't exist at all click `add` and enter the following:

[image]

If that doesn't work, head to `/etc/cron.daily` and make sure that there is a file named `update-notifier-common`.

Comment: It seems the Daily checking is activated from the `Update Manager Settings`.Actually I followed  the process on the tutorial and the hidden startup programs/services were revealed,but it seems that I do not have an entry with the name `Update Notifier`.Do you know how can I add it?

Comment: I edited my answer with a way to add the entry. Does it work now?

Comment: You are very welcome. don't hesitate to ask again if there's something wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

It may help you:

- Open the "Update Manager" application.
- Click on "Settings"
- On "Updates" tab click on "Automatically check for updates" and select Daily.