# How can I stop certain XFCE components from starting with Unity?

Tags: unity, xfce

I've installed Xubuntu-Desktop, and of course this pulled in all the usual xfce components. The only problem I have, is that xfce's notification daemon and xfconfd keep starting with Unity. This means notify-osd is not being used, and I must manually load it every time I log in.

How can I remedy this problem?

Comment: Have you tried [enabling the "hidden" startup entries](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-do-i-add-remove-the-hidden-startup-applications) and going through them one by one to see if there are any XFCE related apps? Disabling their startup through Unity will not interfere with XFCE (the "Startup applications" dialog utilizes the x-gnome-autostart-enabled modifier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed these problems by disabling hidden start up entries as MHC mentioned, and by editing the dbus service files so that xfce's daemon is not used for notifications.