# Hidden Startup Applications

Tags: ubuntu-one, startup-applications

I don't use things like Ubuntu One. How do I disable it from Startup Applications?
I believe it is hidden by default along with some other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and either:

- remove the `NoDisplay=true` lines;
- or make those same lines comments by adding `#` in front of them;
- or replace `true` by `false` in those same lines.

The alternate solution can be easily done in three steps:

1. Summon the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type the two following commands:

   ```
   cd /etc/xdg/autostart/
   sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
   ```

After changing anything you want, you can go back to the previous state by typing this into the terminal:

```
sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=false/NoDisplay=true/g' *.desktop
```

This has been tested in 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04.

Sources:
1. [This answer by chtfn](https://askubuntu.com/a/118084/99886)
2. [How to enable all the apps in the Startup Applications in Ubuntu](http://iloveubuntu.net/how-enable-all-apps-startup-applications-ubuntu-1110)

Comment: It's fine. Just make sure that you search for existing Qs that may help you before yu ask another Q. (That's why I marked it a duplicate.) The +1s were just to welcome you to the community. :-)

Comment: I want to remove Ubuntu One. Can you help me? http://askubuntu.com/questions/353987/remove-ubuntu-one