# Remove Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I don't use Ubuntu One much. How do I remove it?

I've already removed it from Startup Applications as given here: [Hidden Startup Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353917/hidden-startup-applications)

Comment: I've answered yur Q, but it's still a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please visit the FAQs here: [Ubuntu One help - Removing Ubuntu One Client](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-completely-remove-and-reinstall-ubuntu-one/).

Summary:

1. Run the following in a terminal session:

   ```
   killall ubuntuone-login ubuntuone-preferences ubuntuone-syncdaemon
   sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone
   rm -rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone
   rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntuone
   mv ~/Ubuntu\ One/ ~/UbuntuOne_old/
   ```

   If you have UDFs, rename the respective folders. E.g. if you were syncing `Documents` folders, rename it to `Documents_old`.
2. **Delete Ubuntu One token:**

   - Open the Dash by clicking the Ubuntu Logo in the upper left corner.
   - Type: Passw
   - Click Passwords and Encryption Keys.
   - Go to the Passwords tab, click to expand the Password folder, delete the entry called "Ubuntu One"
3. In a terminal session run:

`sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-*`

Comment: Good answer! I voted it up. For step 3 I suggest my answer though.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks for the tip, I've made the edit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone\*
```

Comment: I too upvoted your answer for it does it's reqd to d. :-)