# Stop Ubuntu from showing updates every day

Tags: 20.04, updates, update-manager

My question is a follow-up to [the existing question](https://askubuntu.com/q/492186). Well, I love Ubuntu, but it keeps showing me updates every day. As I am a terminal-friendly guy, so often I update my Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y upgrade && sudo apt -y autoremove && sudo apt -y autoclean
```

However, I don't like to see the popup window so frequently. It somehow distracts me from work. A while ago, I got the following popup:

[image]

As suggested in [an old answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/492282), there is no "Update" application in the startup. Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

Furthermore, the "Software & Updates" utility looks appropriately configured. For example, a screenshot is shown below:

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. **How to stop Ubuntu from showing updates every day?**

Comment: Comment only; but I note you use `apt upgrade` to apply upgrades; you are aware `apt upgrade` does **not** apply all upgrades, so the use of that command can leave some package(s) not upgraded meaning you'll get notifications that *updates are available*.  You can `man apt` to view all options, and please take special note of `apt full-upgrade` will can apply upgrades that `apt upgrade` will skip (splitting upgrades into these options gives you more control!)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it safe to use `full-upgrade` ? I consider `full-upgrade` as `dist-upgrade`. I don't want to move to new LTS accidentally.

Comment: Personally I rarely use `apt upgrade` as my 3 times daily upgrade command uses `full-upgrade`.  The `apt` cannot upgrade you beyond the current release, ie. you're currently on *focal* or 20.04, and the most `apt full-upgrade` (or `dist-upgrade`) can do is change you from 20.04.4 to 20.04.5; ie. there is no change to your release (*focal* or 20.04 still) but upgrade level changes.. To *release-upgrade* requires changes to your sources which `apt` cannot do; Ubuntu uses [`do-release-upgrade` & like tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) to perform that task.

Comment: Thanks for introducing `full-upgrade` to me. I understand.

Comment: fyi:  the only reason to be scared of `dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade` (*at least to me anyway*) is if you have a existing problem in your sources as that can cause damage now; instead of later... but if/when I make a mistake; I'd rather know about it now than leave a *minefield* for later..  (why I use `apt autoremove` & `autoclean` always like you do already!)  If you're concerned you should be avoiding the `-y` which provides AFFIRMATION to the damage before you read the impacts of the command & it asks for confirmation.  fyi: I don't automate my upgrades; I always want to peruse them first