# Remove an application from "Show Applications"

Tags: gui

Just migrated from Windows.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

One of the reasons why I migrated was the lure of being able to customize everything about the GUI.

Recently I was looking at some image files and installed Image Magick. It's now showing on "Show Applications". I don't like the icon so I wanted to remove it, but I was told that it's really important because of some dependencies (weird, because I had to install it first). So, I would like to know if I can just make it not show up in "Show Applications". That'd be useful, because there's a lot of other defaults apps that I don't use but don't want to mess around with.

Thank you for your attention.

Edit:

For anyone who *googles* this, the solution I went with was to backup the `.desktop` files under `./usr/share/applications`, and then delete the originals. It's not a perfect solutions. Updates bring them back. Snap apps (what you install from the "Ubuntu Software" app) can be found in `.var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`. Some software that you install won't be in either. To find those, to the root folder with the Files app, then search for `*.desktop`. You can then right-click the file in question and press on "Open Item Location."

Comment: Your question "Remove appication from show applications" is equal to hide it.. So findout your applications desktop file probably from `/usr/share/applications` if its not a snap app. Then copy the file to `../local/share/applications` and have the line `NoDisplay=true` to hide it and also to survive updates..

Comment: Just for some view https://askubuntu.com/q/69810

Comment: To clarify, did you mean `/usr/local/share/applications`? If yes, it doesn't exist. I created it and copied the file over (not moved, I made a copy), then typed this into the terminal: `sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' display-im6.q16.desktop.desktop`

Nothing happened though.

Comment: I mean `$HOME/.local/share/applications`

Comment: Whats the content of your desktop application.. Try to open it in gedit and add/edit the line NoDisplay= to true

Comment: Logout n login may be required.

Comment: I copied the file (not moved, made a new copy) to `$HOME/ .local/share/applications`, then edited it on gedit and added `NoDisplay=true` at the end. Turned of the laptop and back on. Nothing changed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I edited the original file by adding `NoDisplay=true` to it at the end, but nothing happened either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by removing a desktop file from `/usr/share/applications`.

But it will appear again if the package gets an update.

Comment: Can't seem to find it there.

Comment: It may be `im-config.desktop`

Comment: I looked around in some other folders and concluded that it's probably `display-im6.q16.desktop`. When I look up the app's "about" information, it says that it's Image Magick 6 Q16.